# do postgresql has to be downloaded locally on venv or globally?

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-ec2, django-database

i'm a beginner to django and postgresql. currently i have the following directory structure for a django project
**python3.6 --> venv --> django_project** .now , i want to install postgresql and psycopg2 and use it as a database . do i have to install it in venv with venv activated or install it in python3.6 folder.
also how would the two installations above behave when i try to host the project on AWS ec2.

i have installed postgresql in venv with venv activated and i'm getting the error 'NO module named psycopg2'. what did i do wrong?

Comment: Postgresql is not a python package, and thus has no relation to your python virtual environment

Comment: @BlueStar so, since psycopg2 is a python package. it need to be downloaded in the venv?

Comment: Yes, you'll want to pip install psycopg2 inside of your virtual environment if you want to use it inside of that virtual environment.

Comment: @BlueStar did that. Successfully installed psycopg2 but when tried import psycopg2 in python shell. got import error *No module named psycopg2*  and the application is not running.